# How can i create hyperlinks within the map method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, hyperlink

I have an array of files and I want certain ones to be displayed and hyperlinked. I'm using the map method and when only 1 file displays, it links properly. I need some help with the syntax when multiple files must be displayed.

```
render() {

  const mappings = {
    'P1011': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/Pickering-P1011-May-Verified_Results5.xls',
    'P1511': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PNGS-1511-Verified_Results_2.xls',
    'P1711': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PNGS-P1711_Verified_Results_3.xlsx',
    'P1911': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PLGS_Unit_1-PL1911_VerifiedResults2.xlsx',
  }

   if (this.props.channelSelectedData.length >= 1){
        return(
            <div className="channel-detail-box">
                
                    <p>Outages:
                      <a href={mappings[this.props.channelSelectedData.map(inspection => {
                          return inspection.outage 
                          })]}>
                      {this.props.channelSelectedData.map(inspection => {
                           return inspection.outage + ' '
                          })}</a> 
                    </p> 
            </div>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>No data found</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
render() {
  const mappings = {
    'P1011': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/Pickering-P1011-May-Verified_Results5.xls',
    'P1511': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PNGS-1511-Verified_Results_2.xls',
    'P1711': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PNGS-P1711_Verified_Results_3.xlsx',
    'P1911': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PLGS_Unit_1-PL1911_VerifiedResults2.xlsx',
  }

  const { channelSelectedData } = this.props

  if (channelSelectedData.length === 0) {
    return <div>
      <p>No data found</p>
    </div>
  }

  return <div className="channel-detail-box">
    <p>Outages: {channelSelectedData.map(({ outage }) => <a href={mappings[outage]}>{outage}</a>)}</p>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Try destructuring objects whenever you can it will lead to clearer code. You should read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment. Anyway glad I helped and have a nice day!

Comment: You can usually get away with not using `else` statements if they specify a `return`. Read about it here: https://medium.com/better-programming/why-you-need-to-stop-using-else-statements-5b1fd09dea9e.

Comment: @Ross Sheppard Yes good point! I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the rest of your question correctly, I believe your issue is just using map at the incorrect point. What map does is returns an array of values which in this case would be an array of applicable  tags.

```
render() {

  const mappings = {
    'P1011': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/Pickering-P1011-May-Verified_Results5.xls',
    'P1511': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PNGS-1511-Verified_Results_2.xls',
    'P1711': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PNGS-P1711_Verified_Results_3.xlsx',
    'P1911': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PLGS_Unit_1-PL1911_VerifiedResults2.xlsx',
  }

   if (this.props.channelSelectedData.length >= 1){
        return(
            <div className="channel-detail-box">
                
                    <p>Outages:
                      <>
                      {
                      this.props.channelSelectedData.map(chanel=>{
                          return (
                          <a href={mappings[chanel]}>
                            {chanel+' '}
                          </a> )

                        })
                      }
                      </>
                    </p> 
            </div>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>No data found</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Yup, it was an issue with how I was using map.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
const mappings = {
  'P1011': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/Pickering-P1011-May-Verified_Results5.xls',
  'P1511': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PNGS-1511-Verified_Results_2.xls',
  'P1711': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PNGS-P1711_Verified_Results_3.xlsx',
  'P1911': 'http://192.168.191.128:8080/PLGS_Unit_1-PL1911_VerifiedResults2.xlsx',
};

if (!channelSelectedData || channelSelectedData.length <= 0) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>No data found</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const links = channelSelectedData.map(({ outage }) => (
  <a href={mappings[outage]}>{outage}</a>
));

return (
  <div className="channel-detail-box">
    <p>Outages: {links}</p>
  </div>
);
```